# How to prevent program exits in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and have a problem on running a `ggplot` command. Below is my code. The program exits immediately without showing the diagram. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv(file="./data/assignment-02-data.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")

head(data)
nrow(data)

print(ggplot(data, aes(longitude, latitude)) + geom_point())
```

From this post: [Generate multiple graphics from within an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547306/generate-multiple-graphics-from-within-an-r-function). It says that I need to print the value but it is not working.

I am running the program from shell `./myr.r`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811106/cant-print-to-pdf-ggplot-charts

Comment: For troubleshooting, try adding `Sys.sleep(3)` after your `print` row. In my quick testing, the image won't show because immediately after the "print" command, R exits, killing the plot. If the plot displays for a moment then exits, you'll at least know that your script is doing what you intend.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301694/running-r-scripts-with-plots

Comment: @r2evans I just tried `Sys.sleep(3)`, it gives 3 seconds before program exist but no diagram show during this period time. That means there is something wrong with `ggplot`